# Angular reactive forms input validation not working on load

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am bit new to reactive form validation, trying to achieve input validation on page load, i have simple input field where i need to validate on page load, not manually. Requirement is where i have edit form with bunch of input fields where i am looking for maxLength validation on each field. I tried  with updateValueAndValidity on patchValue/setValue but the error won't show up, any help is much appreciated.

Note: I need to show the error on page load

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpdrjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your StackBlitz example is almost correct. You don't need to call any extra methods after setting the data in your form, like `.updateValueAndValidity()`, you're just checking for the error state incorrectly:

```
<span *ngIf="sampleForm.get('inputTxt').hasError(maxLength)">
  Max(10) letters reached!!!
</span>
```

should be:

```
<span *ngIf="sampleForm.get('inputTxt').hasError('maxlength')">
  Max(10) letters reached!!!
</span>
```

See this updated StackBlitz for a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2fvyqj

Comment: Ah!!!, such a small thing, fresh set of eyes always helps, thank you for your time Brandon